# struggling with sessions implementation

Tags: php, html, session

Today i am learning how to use sessions and after doing some research and trying to add sessions to my code i ran into a few problems. First i would appreciate if someone looks at my login page below and let me know if my session is set up correctly:

login page (index.php):

```
<?PHP

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$file = file_get_contents("data.txt");
if(!strstr($file, "$username||$password"))
{
print '<script> alert ("Sorry! You have entered a Invalid Username or Password.");   window.location="index.php"; </script>';   
}
if(empty($username))
{
print '<script> alert ("Sorry! You have entered a Invalid Username or Password.");   window.location="index.php"; </script>';   
}
else
{
    function validateUser()
{
    session_regenerate_id ();
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}
header("Location: /home.php");
}
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:500px; height:500px; border: 2px solid black;  margin:auto">

<?php include "header.php"; ?>

<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE; width:500px; height:400px; float: left">
<br>
<form  align="center" method="post" action="index.php" >
Username:
<input type="text" name="username" />
<br/>
<br/>
Password:
<input type="password" name="password" />
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/>
<input type="button" value="Register" onclick="document.location='registration.php'" />
</form>
</div>

<?php include "footer.php"; ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Next when the user logs in i want the session to continue throughout all the pages, so this is is my home page (home.php):

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:500px; height:500px; border: 2px solid black;  margin:auto">

<?php include "header.php"; ?>

<?php include "toolbar.php"; ?>

<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE; width:500px; height:375px; float:  left">
<p align="center"><?php echo "<b>Welcome</b>, " . $_SESSION['username']; ?></p>

<form align="center" method="link" action="practice.php">
 <input type="submit" value="Practice Mode">
</form>
</div>

<?php include "footer.php"; ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure if i am doing this correctly, i read that i must uses session_start() on every page to continue session, but when i try to display the name of the user that logs in as a welcome message, it doesn't seem to work.

Also i made a kind of menu bar that displays the logged in user which will be included on every page, but again the user name is not displayed:

Menubar (toolbar.php):

```
<div id="toolbar" style="width:500px; clear:both; height:25px">
 <table border="0">
 <tr>
 <td>
 <form align="left" method="link" action="home.php">
 <input type="submit" value="Home">
 </form>
 </td>
 <td style="width:400px"><div align="center"><?php echo "Logged in as: ". $_SESSION['username']; ?></div></td>
 <td>
 <form align="right" method="link" action="index.php">
 <input type="submit" value="Logout">
 <?php session_destroy(); ?>
 </form>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

And the last thing, i attempted to make the logout button in the menu bar but im not sure whether it works correctly or not.

I would appreciate if someone could review this code and give me some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `session_start()` before you started to set or initializes the value in it

```
<?PHP
function validateUser($username)
 {
  session_start();
  session_regenerate_id();
  $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 }



if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$file = file_get_contents("data.txt");
if(!strstr($file, "$username||$password"))
{
print '<script> alert ("Sorry! You have entered a Invalid Username or Password.");   window.location="index.php"; </script>';   
}
if(empty($username))
{
print '<script> alert ("Sorry! You have entered a Invalid Username or Password.");   window.location="index.php"; </script>';   
}
else
{
   validateUser($username);// changed here 
   header("Location: /home.php");
   exit();
}
}
?>
```

Remove `<?php session_destroy(); ?>` from toolbar.php.

Logout:

```
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

In logout.php:

```
  <?php @session_start();
   session_unset($_SESSION['username']);
   $_SESSION['username']="";
   session_destroy(); 
  // header("location:yourhomepage.php");
   echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=yourhomepage.php">';
   exit();
 ?>
```

Comment: thank you this works, but can you tell me how should i implement the logout button?

Comment: i am getting the following error when clicking logout: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\logout.php:1) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\logout.php on line 6

Comment: Updated answer please check

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a guess here, but try changing:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    session_start();
```

to

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
```

This will initialse the session on the initial get, as well as in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `<?php session_destroy(); ?>` in toolbar.php.

Because when you `<?php include "toolbar.php"; ?>` in home.php, you are destroying the session before it should be destroyed.